# Importance of replIndexprefetch

Tags: mongodb

This is regarding the paramter replIndexprefetch in mongodb replica-set: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongod/#cmdoption-mongod--replIndexPrefetch

**I am confused for two reasons**

1. If there are extra indexes, then mongod, at some point of time, has to fetch them before
   applying the changes from oplog
2. Are there some difference in
   performance related to enabling/disabling this parameters

Comment: One thought: The _id index might not always be the one that sxatisfies replication for MongoDB, i.e. you might get a index of `{_id:1,some_other_fields_about_20_of_them:1}` so to do this means that MongoDB will only load the default _id index and not some other (possibly) heavier index

Comment: @Sammaye : My doubt is same, anyways mongod has to fetch all the related index that has to be updated. Then what is the point of telling to fetch _id index only.

Comment: I think updating an index is different to fetching it, I need to look into it some more

Comment: @Sammaye
As per I rem, for any write operation (say update), which don't involve the index keys, then mongodb won't fetch that index (given no document move happens). Do you know about this?

Given, above it correct, then use case of replIndexprefetch is not making any sense to me.

Comment: Yea, I mean it shouldn't fetch indexes it doesn't need, however, for when it does contain those indexes keys (which is what I thought you mean't by fetch irrespective of only allowing the _id index to be fetched) is that updating index keys is different to "fetching" the index, I think it updates differently, in a more performant manner than having to fetch it into the working set when replication on the members occurs pulling the oplog from the primary down to their own but I have not checked the code to it, however, if that is not the case then that option does confuse me as well

Comment: When we have to update the index, then we have to fetch the index?
I am sure that update to index won't be done lazily.

Comment: That I am unsure of, I wouldn't mind seeing how they update the index, maybe that is where this option makes sense however, I haven't programmed C++ in such a long time I have forgotten how to read it but might try and take a look later

Comment: Thanks for the effort